# How to pass an object to a method using reflection in java

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I am working on some code which takes a string input dynamically , so i chose reflection as i didnt find any other better approach for it ,

**My current code:**

```
Class xyzClass = Class.forName("com.example.Xyz");

Object abcObj =  abcService.generateAbcObj("some string input");
Method method = xyzClass.getDeclaredMethod("add", abcObj); // i want to pass this abcObj to this declared method add but getDeclaredMethod takes class as a parameter
```

Can anybody suggest way to do in reflection as i want it in a dynamic way or any other way to achieve it in a better sense ?

Comment: what is  `abcService `

Comment: Abc service is simple service that does some unmarshalling and return me some object ..it has nothing to do with dynamic whereas xyzClass is dynamic one as it auto generated so I just want how I can pass that abcObj to method in reflection

Comment: When the class is dynamically loaded, you should say exactly that. The best approach is to let the dynamic class implement an interface that is available at compile-time, so you only need to load and instantiate the class dynamically, followed by using it via the interface. Otherwise, you have to do it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818072/2711488)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `class` (because you first has to identify the method you want to call, and then call it, and without the class of the parameters, you could get a method overloading that is not the one you want):

```
Method method = xyzClass.getDeclaredMethod("add", abcObj.getClass());
```

and then you can invoke it:

```
method.invoke(/*instance of com.example.Xyz on which you want to call add*/, abcObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow a method to modify an argument, you must pass in an object. Objects in Java are also passed by value, however, the value of an object is a reference. So, the effect is that the object is passed in by reference. ([For more info](https://www.andrews.edu/%7Ebidwell/java.book/java/javaOO/arguments.html#:%7E:text=To%20allow%20a%20method%20to,a%20reference%20to%20the%20object.))

With reflection where you are passing the object to the method, you should use `Method.invoke`. As you've got a single parameter do this:

```
method.invoke(this, abcObj);
```